# Subsetting columns by a string variable returns NULL in R

Tags: r, subset

I can subset a column  named A from a data frame `x_data` using  `x_data$A`.
But if I do

```
some_string<-'A'
x_data$some_string
```

I get NULL.
Can someone please explain why is it so. Thanks.

Comment: On the second line, R will only look for the symbol `some_string` within `x_data`. It doesn't matter whether you have a variable `some_string` defined in the global environment or not, as R won't look there.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference a data frame with the `$` operator using a string literal, only a column.  If you want to subset using a string, use the list syntax:

```
sub_df <- x_data[[some_string]]
```

Comment: Thanks . This helps a lot.